# Need Help Setting Up Item to Item Recommendation with Tensorflow Recommenders

Tags: python, tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to build a model that gives similar items to a queried item using Tensorflow Recommenders.  The data that I have to work with is a Pandas DataFrame where each row (indexed by a guid) represents an item and each column is an element in a vector that defines the features of the item, similar to the following form:

| id | 0 | 1 | ... | 98 | 99 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90e8895c-2540-49b3-97d7-53b92eb3ceeb | -1.695247 | 2.693680 | ... | -2.049504 | -0.898866 |
| a00a7e77-84fe-40ed-a14e-8a14498a5340 | -1.929445 | 2.139853 | ... | 0.363655 | -1.842822 |
| b3965aeb-2322-4004-bf9d-9df1126a01a5 | 0.032137 | -1.213446 | ... | -2.737837 | 2.702708 |
| 4cd68683-e003-4fc8-a0c6-cdbc9dc42a7d | 0.812185 | -1.820207 | ... | 0.469358 | 0.079269 |
| 7d61e408-b5bd-4e36-899d-d16dcd9fceaf | 0.293615 | -2.182612 | ... | -1.058641 | -2.298465 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 643eb395-5f9d-41c9-8526-c67a10038277 | 1.386834 | 2.177462 | ... | -1.981660 | 0.853934 |
| 809a15b4-5826-403f-a0bc-06a4b06acd47 | -1.730925 | -2.583835 | ... | -2.462176 | -2.852735 |
| f1366efb-2fb3-4003-9aca-361715d07fb4 | -1.321683 | -0.951181 | ... | -1.109261 | -0.469597 |
| e386cc6f-1fa4-4c25-92c0-4c9d0c0cedca | -0.506157 | 0.874127 | ... | -1.742643 | -2.081506 |
| 07129345-0962-4051-a1f3-79d823d1798e | -2.404405 | -0.834061 | ... | -0.412421 | -0.350780 |

In the end, I'd like to be able to provide the model with one of these guids and get a list of guids in return that are most similar to the queried item as determined by the model.

I've tried to use [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval) as an example, substituting the user/ratings side of the data with another tower for movies, but there's a lot that's unclear to me and I don't know where to start.

For now I don't care as much about what the layers or activation functions look like as I do simply having a working model that runs all the way through.

1. How do I structure the original dataframe to be a TF dataset that I can use for the model?
   The example looks like it uses the names of movies but my data doesn't have any strings apart from the guids.
2. How do I map the guids to the vector given by the row, within the model?
3. How do I build each tower so that I can get reasonable results?